# Separate the Whole and Decimal number in a Textbox

Tags: vb.net

Lets say I have 3 `textboxes` and `textbox1 = 32.07` how can I separate the whole number and the decimal? So the output would be like this:

Textbox2 = 32.00
Textbox3 = 7.00

Comment: you really want .07 to be 7.00? for what reason if I may ask?

Comment: Sure. this is the procedure in my system they are times that the item will be received as whole and in pcs and whole will act as whole number and pcs will act as the decimal. lets say i received an item with this qty "12.01" that means 12 box and 1 pcs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if textbox1.text.contains(".") Then
Textbox2.text=val(textbox1.text.split(".")(0))
Textbox3.text=val(textbox1.text.split(".")(1))
else
Textbox2.text=textbox1.text
Textbox3.text="0"
end if
```

Comment: TYSM I will approve this after 2 mins